# How to send notification to specific user from web application to mobile application

Tags: java, android, spring, push-notification, onesignal

I have a web application and mobile application to manage user parcels. Now, i want when a user receives a parcel, send a notification from web application to him on mobile application.

I used [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) and connected my mobile app successfully, but don't know which and how call an api to send notification to specific user?

Also, I read the documentation, but couldn't find any way and example for this requirement

Comment: you can send push notification using unique token generated by device

Comment: I know, but how can i get unique device token for specific user?

Comment: using `MyInstanceIDListenerService` https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

Comment: I mean how can i access that token in my website and call api with that token?

Comment: you can send that token during login from device and store at server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular way to send push notification to mobile devices is by using **Google Firebase push notification**.

Every device is tracked by unique device token generated by Firebase ( Android or iOS ).

**Solution for your Usecase:**

- Whenever user tries to login into your application just trigger an API call to backend.
- That API will put an entry to the database with userId and device token.
- When you going to send push notification just get the device token from the database based on userId using Firebase SDK.

**Example:**

To send notification for multiple device ids that may be Android or IOS.

You can use MulticastMessage in fireBase.

```
                    MulticastMessage multiCast = MulticastMessage.builder()
                        .putAllData(new HashMap<String, String>() { put("message":"hi"); })
                        .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder().build())
                        .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().build())
                        .addAllTokens(Arrays.asList("devicetoken1", "devicetoken2"))
                        .build();
```

**For reference :** https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message